# CI/CD in GitHub repositories

Tags: continuous-integration

I want to create a simple CI/CD GitHub system for academic purposes and better understanding of the system. I want to know how can I check if a repository was updated or how can I call and API every time a commit is done. I thought about using GitHub Actions but I think is better if I could do this configurations in the system instead of going in each repository on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub Actions is the best way to get started with CI/CD, in my opinion. It's well integrated with GitHub, which most people are already familiar with, and it's plethora of tools are well documented in easy-to-follow tutorials on the GitHub website. If you don't have a very good reason not to use GitHub Actions, and are trying to learn, I would suggest you reconsider.

If you are hellbent on not using GitHub actions, where are you deploying the application? If Azure, use Azure's pipelines (it's the exact same syntax as github actions, btw.); if using AWS or GCP, use the respective CI/CD pipeline UIs offered by those platforms. If you're hosting/deploying on your own machine using something like GitLab, its syntax is very similar to GitHub Actions anyway, and GitLab has good documentation and tutorials as well.

So basically, your options are to use GitHub Actions, which is easy to pick up and highly recommended, or use the pipeline of whichever service you're using to deploy your application.